# Vuejs router won't load on live server

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a Vue2/Laravel 7 project working locally on my server using `http://examplesite.test`. It's using Vue router and all is good. However when I load it on to a live server with the example URL structure `http://example.com/folder1/folder2/` Vue router fails to load anything into `<div id="app">`, I just get the following:

```js
<div id="app">
   <!---->
</div>
```

I know it's Vue Router because if I were to put a normal Vue component in place of the router component, it loads fine. There are no errors in the console at all. What must I do to Vue Js router (or maybe Vue in general) to make it work when there's extra folder paths in the URL structure?

My Vue router is set up like this:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});
```

The web path is thus:

```js
Route::get('home/{path?}', 'HomeController@index')
    ->where('path', '.*')
    ->name('home');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using vue-router, the current route is rendered inside a `router-view` component. So your app would look like this:

```
<div id="app">
   <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**But**, it seems you're using Laravel routing? I don't know a lot about Laravel, but vue-router is only used when making single page applications. If you're doing routing in Laravel, you may not need vue-router at all.